# Read Res1D file Return Pandas DataFrame

Tags: mikeio

I would like to read a Res1D resultfile into a Pandas dataframe, which seems simple enough following the examples on GitHub. But the import fails with the error:

"TypeError: sequence item 1: expected str instance, NoneType found"

My code is simply:

```
In [1]: from mikeio.res1d import Res1D

In [2]: df = Res1D('NW_CDS5_kf-1.25_1Base.res1d').read()
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-2-24ada8fb81e2>", line 1, in <module>
    df = Res1D('NW_CDS5_kf-1.25_1Base.res1d').read()

  File "C:\Arkiv\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\mikeio\res1d.py", line 158, in read
    return self.read_all()

  File "C:\Arkiv\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\mikeio\res1d.py", line 173, in read_all
    for values, col_name in Res1D.get_values(

  File "C:\Arkiv\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\mikeio\res1d.py", line 186, in get_values
    col_name = col_name_delimiter.join([data_item.Quantity.Id, name])

TypeError: sequence item 1: expected str instance, NoneType found
```

Any ideas of what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the following?

```py
from mikeio.res1d import Res1D
df = Res1D('NW_CDS5_kf-1.25_1Base.res1d')
df.read()
```

Please note that in the latest version of mikeio, the Res1d functions have been moved to a new repository: `mikeio1d`

https://github.com/DHI/mikeio1d

Comment: Yes, i have tried that also. I also just tried installing mikeio1d, but it produces the samme error. I know the resultfile works, because i can open it in Mike View just fine.

I tried your suggested code:

`from mikeio1d.res1d import Res1D

res1d = Res1D('1D.res1D')
df = res1d.read()`

Comment: Have you tried other types of res1d files? E.g. rivermodel, pipenetwork. Would you be able to upload the res1d file here? I've tried the code on my own res1d-file, and it works, so I think the module is not able to read all types of results in a res1d-file.

Comment: First I only tried resultfiles from Mike Urban (pipenetwork). I have just tried a Mike Hydro River resultfile, which works.